# visio like adge aggregation in graphviz

Tags: java, graphviz

Can graphviz do edge aggregation like visio ? meaning something like

```
      o
      |
-------------
|   |   |   |
o   o   o   o
```

and if not does any other java tool can ?

Our customers are used to this kind of layout and I cant find the way to do it using graphviz

Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graphviz uses the term *"concentrate"* to refer to that functionality.  See [this page of the Graphfiz Wiki for more info.](http://www.graphviz.org/mywiki/FaqMerge)

Comment: great, thanks, can it also use straight folded lines as in the above illustration?

Comment: I don't know if it can do straight lines.  I've never had a need for that from Graphviz.